# Is it feasible to try and classify an enclosed space as being a. Very crowded b. Less crowded & c. Sparsely crowded using image processing?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, face-detection

The idea is to get three classifications for crowd: High, low and medium based on an image captured inside a train compartment. Something like this:
[image]

This gets classified in the 'High' category

http://www.spiceflair.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/14a.jpg 
This perhaps in the 'Medium' & so on.

Comment: This may be a more suitable question to ask in tbe cross validated forum - they're for machine learning type questions. My best guess is if you have access to a training set, compare some test statistic of a wavelet transform which could allow you to classify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is research being done on crowd monitoring/crowd counting, which is similar to what you are looking for. The [UCSD Vision Lab](http://www.svcl.ucsd.edu/) is doing work on this.

Here is a paper from this lab that estimates the size of crowds [[PDF](http://www.svcl.ucsd.edu/publications/conference/2008/cvpr08/cvpr08_peoplecnt.pdf)].

It is not exactly the same as your train scenario, but the idea is something that could be used for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds feasible (and fun!), but it will be hard to get very accurate.  My guess is that, like your tags suggest, this would be a combination of edge detection / space detection to get a measure of density and face/hand detection to get a measure of human content.  You could then train up an SVM or RandomForest model on the data, tweak, and repeat.